# Is it possible to split a xml string into elements in array?

Tags: java

Suppose I have xml string.

```
String str="<loan><account>123456</account><name>RamaKrishna</name><principle>1000</principle><issue_date>Jan-1-2013</issue_date><interest_rate>12%</interest_rate></loan>"
```

My output should be like

```
arr = ["<account>123456</account>","<name>RamaKrishna</name>","<principle>1000</principle>","<issue_date>Jan-1-2013</issue_date>","<interest_rate>12%</interest_rate>"]
```

Comment: you'll have to write your own implementation, I guess

Comment: I think you can use `JAXB` to create an object from your XML String. That object should contain the properties like account,name etc. Then from that object you can get the different values of those properties and prepare the array accordingly.

Comment: better to use any  `XML Document ` Reader is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will be static (just answering your question) and like @Vikrant Kashyap mentions XML Documents can be a better option for a more generic solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Orginal string, remove the loan tags
    String str="<loan><account>123456</account><name>RamaKrishna</name><principle>1000</principle><issue_date>Jan-1-2013</issue_date><interest_rate>12%</interest_rate></loan>";
    str = str.replace("<loan>", "");
    str = str.replace("</loan>", "");

    //Create an array of the string
    List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            list.add(c);
    }       

    //Result
    ArrayList<String> tmp = XmlComma(list);

}
```

And the XmlComma method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> XmlComma(List<Character> input) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i != (input.size() -1))
            {
                if(!input.get(i).equals(','))
                {
                    output += input.get(i);
                }
                if(input.get(i).equals('>') && input.get(i+1).equals('<'))
                {               
                    result.add(output);
                    output = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output += '>';
                result.add(output);
            }
        }
        return result;      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

> String[] split = str.split("(?=(<[^\/]+>?<\/.*?>))");

If you're trying to keeps the tags intact.
?= shall preserve your tags, however remove the last loan tag separately, this will work without nesting. If not preserving tags, you could just do:

> String[] split = s.split("<.*?>");